# How many projects are there which implement ERC1155 standard?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, erc-1155, nft

New ERC1155 standard which is thought to be an improved version of ERC721 and ERC20.
 But I see many projects still prefer ERC20 or ERC721 standards. 
If so, do you know any projects implementing ERC1155? If so, do you know why did they implement that standard?

Comment: Voting down as off topic

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Hi, what do you think if this question is edited to something like "What are the differences between ERC-721 and ERC-1155?"

Answer (score 1):

Relative adoption is partly down to the fact that the other two are legacy systems that have been in the consciousness of the blockchain community a lot longer. Partly it could also be down to some projects not requiring the richer set of features that ERC-1155 offers.

For a token standard that's only been confirmed since mid-June, ERC-1155 has some pretty good traction already though (in my opinion, of course).

It's officially supported by major projects like **0x** and **Gnosis**.

Probably fair to say though that thus far, the bulk of adoption is from games and gaming projects.

## **GAMING ADOPTION**

ERC-1155 is more about bringing regular videogames onto the blockchain, than about powering crypto-games, where earning cryptocurrency is the primary consideration of game mechanics and gameplay(and where legacy standards like 721 may still hold sway).

**Horizon Games** (developers of Skyweaver), and **Pixowl** (developers of The Sandbox) helped co-create the standard along with the team from Enjin, who have brought a whole bunch of other games onboard adoption-wise.

In terms of Enjin-based ERC-1155s, there's a good 30+ of them in development right now that have officially partnered with Enjin, across a variety of gaming genres. Cool ones to check out might be **Age of Rust**, **Dissolution**, **9 Lives Arena**, **Space Misfits**, and **Forgotten Artifacts**.

I've also seen some gaming properties out there featuring (and promoting) ERC-1155 integration that haven't got any official links with Enjin, including Cryptonoms, Etherlegends, and Arena Match Gold (an eSports platform).

## **NON-GAMING ADOPTION**

There's also some non-gaming application of the ERC-1155 standard, even if it doesn't get quite as much attention right now. It can be used to tokenise a variety of things that can be portrayed digitally, from trophies, to charitable donations, to reward programs, to discount vouchers, to concert tickets.

**GDAC** and **Kriptomat** have used it to both gameify the exchange experience and power loyalty programs.

**Beyond Horizon** and **Reewardio** exist to foster creation and adoption of ERC-1155 solutions in the retail space.

ERC-1155 tokens have been used to both attract and enhance charitable donations for the **SENS Foundation** (a favourite of Vitalik), **Stack Up**, and **GameChanger**.

One thing to bear in mind about current adoption levels is that most of the tools Enjin have built to help simplify the process of ERC-1155 token creation for non-blockchain audiences are still on testnet, meaning there's a limit to how much tangible adoption can actually happen right now. Once the blockchain SDKs and plugins go live on the Ethereum mainnet, we should start seeing a lot more adoption, since pretty much anyone will be able to start using the token standard.

Comment: This smells like spam. Especially from a new account that has never before and never since posted anything else. And especially after I have seen hyperbole used by the team which was marketing those projects in October 2019, the time this comment was made.